# DM-theory definition: To what side does a carinality of an entity refer?

Tags: data-modeling, cardinality

Of cource there is a cardinality of a relation, for example (0-1 : 1-n).
But can you express something like: "The cardinality of A in this relation is 0-1" or "The cardinality of B in this relation is 1-n."

I am building a meta data model for data modeling and I want to name the properties for the two entities` cardinalities (something like cardinality_a_min, ..._max, ...b_min, ...b_max). Of cource I can write comments to ensure that everybody knows to which side these properties refer to. But I am wondering if this question is well defined in theory.

I know that in one ERD-Notation A (0-1) : (1-n) B means that there are many As and in another notation it means that there are many Bs. So is this true also for the data modeling theory? Or is it clearly defined?
The problem of saying "The cardinality of A is 1-n" could be the following: Do I have many As now or does an A point to many other entities?

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the cardinality of an attribute in a relation as the number of values from that attribute's domain that can be associated with each valid combination of values from the other attributes in the relation. For example:

In a 1:M relation (e.g. a relation (A,B) with candidate key B), each value in A can be associated with many values in B, and each value in B can be associated with a single value in A.

1:1 and M:N relations are straightforward, I won't enumerate them. This approach holds for higher-degree relations as well:

In a M:N:1 relation (e.g. a relation (A,B,C) with candidate key A,B), each combination of A,B values can be associated with a single value from C. Every other combination of values from one or more domains can be associated with many values from the remaining domains.

In a M:1:1 relation (e.g. a relation (A,B,C) with candidate key A), each A value can be associated with a single combination of B and C. Each B value can be associated with many combinations of A and C, and each C with many A,B.

In the last example, take care to avoid the notion that "each B is associated with a single C". Associations occur along functional or multivalued dependency lines, in this case via A. In other words, each B is associated with many A, each of which is associated with one C. Transitively, each B is associated with many C, and vice versa.

For more detail on this topic, I suggest you study the logical foundation of data modeling closely. Particular topics include functional and multivalued dependencies in relations and Armstrong's axioms.